# Kubernetes Cluster stuck on removing PV/PVC

Tags: kubernetes

I am been struggling to get my simple 3 node Kubernetes cluster running.

```
$ kubectl get nodes                                                                                    NAME   STATUS   ROLES         AGE   VERSION
ubu1   Ready    master        31d   v1.13.4
ubu2   Ready    master,node   31d   v1.13.4
ubu3   Ready    node          31d   v1.13.4
```

I tried creating a PVC,  which was stuck in Pending forever. So I deleted it, but now it is stuck in Terminating status.

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                        STATUS        VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
task-pv-claim               Terminating   task-pv-volume   100Gi      RWO            manual            26d
```

How can I create a PV that is properly created and useable for the demos described on the official kubernetes web site?

PS: I used `kubespray` to get this up and running.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 VMs, this is the Docker version installed:

```
ubu1:~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.2-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        6d37f41
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 03:47:56 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried first removing `.metadata.finalizers` from your PV/PVC and then delete the PV/PVC?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma where do I find this to remove? I don't have it in the YAML deployment files.

Comment: You can use `$ kubectl edit pvc <pvc_name>` command. Then the yaml configuration will appear on your terminal with the default editor (specified by $KUBE_EDITOR environment variable may be). If it is open with `vim` or `vi` then run appropriate command to remove those line or do as what you need for the editor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use following command to delete the PV or PVC forcefully.

```
#kubectl delete pvc <PVC_NAME> --grace-period=0 --force
```

in your case

```
#kubectl delete pvc task-pv-claim  --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: I've marked it as the correct answer. Thank you! That worked flawlessly. I can now bang my head against sharing a local dir on all 2 nodes (ubu2 and ubu3). Any hints there?

Comment: do you want to share one direction in one host to 2 ubuntu?

Comment: @yasin_lachini I'll take one or bi-directional at this point to just get this off the ground. :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: My understanding of your setup is: 1 server running 3 VMs contatinig Ubuntu cluster nodes. To share local directory you need to mount local directory to your VMs (way to do this is dependent upon your VM engine), and then create PV with volume type `hostPath` and Access Mode `ReadWriteMany` so it can be claimed by many pods.

Answer (score 88):

`kubectl edit pv (pv name)`

Find the following in the manifest file

```yaml
finalizers:
  -  kubernetes.io/pv-protection
```

... and delete it.

Then exit, and run this command to delete the pv

```bash
kubectl delete pv (pv name) --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: I had an issue with deleting both PV and PVC. This solution also works for deleting pvc.

Comment: confirm. works well.

Comment: This is what worked, the `patch` command didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Did work for me perfectly even without the options.

Comment: Still hangs for me, even with the grace period and force options.

Comment: It's 2023 why do I have to do this

Answer (score 60):

```
kubectl patch pvc {PVC_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

You need to patch the PVC to set the “finalizers” setting to null, this allows the final unmount from the node, and the PVC can be deleted.

Comment: The same can be done with `pv`

Comment: on windows you need to escape the quotes, but you knew that right? `kubectl patch pvc {PVC_NAME} -p '{\"metadata\":{\"finalizers\":null}}'`

Comment: how do i do this for all the pvc's instead of doing one by one.. I have lots of pvs stuck in terminating state

Comment: This is the same solution as the top answer, I think, just better because it also deletes any other finalizers that are blocking you and doesn't require a hand edit.

Answer (score 14):

For quick eyes :

```
kubectl patch pvc <pvc_name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'

kubectl delete pvc <pvc_name> --grace-period=0 --force 

kubectl patch pv <pv_name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'

kubectl delete pv <pv_name> --grace-period=0 --force
```

Answer (score 3):

if your PV or PVC stuck then delete related pods and your terminating status PV or PVC will no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a describe command

```
kubectl describe pvc <pvcname>
```

you can see the resource, which is using and blocking the deleting:

```
Used By: <podname>
```

After deleting the resource, the related pvc will be deleted too.