# Why removing finalizers with kubectl patch does no work for PVC in Terminating Status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, patch

Trying to automate removing `.metadata.finalizers` when it's needed:

```bash
  kubectl -n ${ns} patch pvc $pvcname -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
```

Checking again with `get pvc` , but I found it same value.. What i am missing here ?

Note,if i edit the resource directly with `kubectl edit` , the change takes effect.

Comment: Can you please have a try with below command and paste the errors if any :
 `kubectl -n ${ns} patch pvc {pvcname} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}' --type=merge`.

Refer this [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) doc and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672498/kubernetes-clustsr-stuck-on-removing-pv-pvc) for more information.


      **Note** : If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.